# react - react-table with n number of columns

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-table

I am trying to use react-table and so far its working great but I am having trouble trying to figure out how I can cater for the number of my columns being dynamic, depending on the results of an input passed. I am testing each function against an arbitrary number of test cases and showing my results using react-table. The columns look something like

Name, Test Case 1, Test Case 2, .... Test Case n

Now I don't know what the value of n will be. It will differ for each test file. So how do I create columns for these test cases given I don't know how many they will be?

Comment: Code sample? What have you tried? It's hard for anyone to answer these types of questions without seeing what you've already done.

Comment: Okay let me share one.

Comment: I was able to solve it by doing:  var numCases = Object.keys(test_cases).length 
  var temp = [...Array(numCases).keys()].map(x => ++x)
  temp.map(num => columns.push( {id: 'Test Case ' + num, Header: 'Test Case ' + num, accessor: d => d[num] } ) )
It turned out to be pretty simple in the end :)